# How to change combobox selected values display order

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I would like to change selected records display order in a combobox. The reason is that, as you can see from the screen shot, the combobox list so long therefore employee can't see selected values easily. Are there any method/function to change displayed value sort order based on the selected record index?

[image]

Comment: I think the real question may be, is a combobox the way to go. If it is long enough that you have to sort it then you may want to think of an alternative.

Comment: Dear Jeff, I thought so but employee's don't know the record names.

Comment: Wouldn't a combo with multiple selection be a simpler approach? See the 3rd example on [this page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/form/combos.html).

Comment: Dear Rixo, I did that sample but as you can see the list names so long as well, isn't feasible for me :(

Comment: Then maybe the second example on [this page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html) would be easier for you to implement, even if it is arguably less user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [sort](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Sortable-method-sort) the store with a [custom function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter-cfg-sorterFn). That will be reflected in the combo box.

That would be something like:

```
combo.getStore().sort([{
    sorterFn: function(a, b) {
        if (a.get('selected')) {
            if (b.get('selected')) {
                return a.get('name').localeCompare(b.get('name'));
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (b.get('selected')) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return a.get('name').localeCompare(b.get('name'));
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Dear rixo, If I am not mistaken `a,b` selected value and target value, right?

Comment: `a` and `b` are two records to compare. Return value of `-1` means a is before `b`, `1` the reverse, and `0` that they have the same order (see the doc for [`sorterFn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter-cfg-sorterFn)).

Comment: The problem with my example code is that I don't know how you handle the selection state of a record, so I assumed that would be reflected in one of the record's fields ("selected", in my example).

Comment: The other option would be maintain another field like sortid in store and by default add a value 100 or increase the current id value+100. when ever user selects the record update the record with a value less than 100 or decrease the current id value-100. Use that in field in store sortfields